# Multiple Guard authenticators in an OR relationship

Tags: symfony, authentication

I'm using Symfony 2.8's new Guard Authentication system, and I'd like to allow users to authenticate using *either one* of two methods. So I've implemented Guard authenticators for both and configured them like so:

```
security:
  firewalls:
    my_firewall:
      pattern: ^/some-pattern
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - my_first_auth
          - my_second_auth
        entry_point: my_first_auth
```

The problem is that they *both* run, so if the user is successful on the first, but unsuccessful on the second, he gets a forbidden response. In this scenario, I'd like him to be successful.

Is there a way to configure multiple Guard authenticators in an OR relationship, so that if the first one succeeds, the second one is skipped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end I manually implemented a solution myself, taking advantage of the fact that if `getCredentials()` returns null, the authenticator is skipped. Both authenticators have code that looks like this:

```
class MyAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator {
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage) {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request) {
        if ($this->isAlreadyAuthenticated()) {
            return null; // Skip this authenticator
        }
        // Get the credentials and continue with this authenticator
    }

    protected function isAlreadyAuthenticated() {
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
        return $token && $token->isAuthenticated();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to do the same in the `supports()` method instead ?

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it given the configuration you have. The behaviour in the case of multiple guard authenticators is exactly the one you described: they both run.

As an alternative, I would recommend using [Security Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/voters.html), I think you'll have more luck this way, although I don't know how exactly the implementation should look like.

Comment: Voter should be used for user permissions, and not for user authentication. They are two completely different things.

Answer (score -1):

Your example is superficial, you should describe better use case. If you want simple answer there is nothing like OR.

But if your getCredentials method returns null authentication is skipped [see this](https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Guard/Firewall/GuardAuthenticationListener.php#L101) so second should run (didn't test this).

Other solution how to do what you want is have one Authenticator and resolve credentials from request or cookie or whatever in getCredentials method.

Comment: Don't know why downvote. My answer was actually used to solve problem according to author own answer.